# jQuery conflicts with mobilymap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a web-page in joomla with jquery plugin and tried to add a mobilymap js.
When I put all scripts to load correctly, the front-end doesn't show me map currectly and firebug shows me an error: TypeError: $j(...).mobilymap is not a function

Heres my js:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){
    $j(".europe_map").mobilymap({
        position: 'center',
        popupClass: 'bubble',
        markerClass: 'point',
        popup: true,
        cookies: true,
        caption: true,
        setCenter: true,
        navigation: false,
        navSpeed: 1000,
        navBtnClass: 'navBtn',
        outsideButtons: '.map_buttons a',
        onMarkerClick: function(){},
        onPopupClose: function(){},
        onMapLoad: function(){}
    });
});
```

Link of my frontview http://www.gloper.org/highplay.pt/index.php/quem-somos/mundo

Could anybody help me please??

Comment: Looking at the source error that came up, and taking a look at init.js, the jQuery.noConflict() is not on the live site? have you uploaded the file?

Comment: Hi Rory. Sorry, the site was cached. I have this on my <head>
`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".europe_map").mobilymap();
    });`
Is that right??

Comment: if you have called var `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` then `$(".europe_map").mobilymap();` is incorrect as jQuery can only be access through either `jQuery` or `$j`, your code should now read `$j(".europe_map").mobilymap();`

Comment: I needed to make some changes. But now appears 3 errors (2 with the same js). `ReferenceError: $j is not defined $j(".demo1").craftmap();`.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of your site, i can see two issues.

First this file 
/highplay.pt/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js

This needs to be
`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` it's currently `jQuery.noConflict();`

secondly you are including the jQuery library in your project twice! once minified right above your no conflict script, which is good. But further down the page, you include another unminified version of jQuery right above your craftmap!

`<script src="/highplay.pt/templates/legacy/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/highplay.pt/templates/legacy/js/craftmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

If you remove that version of jQuery and just keep the minified version at the top, it should resolve your issues

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks you so much RoryPickering, you're the man! :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries Francisco, glad I could help! :)

Comment: Just another question, if you could help me. I am working on CSS for responsive web and I saw that this wont appears on mobile, but just in this site (I actually tested it on another http://www.gloper.org/mapa/index.html with the SAME content of map and works fine). I forced the img tag with ` height: 320px !important; ` but doesn't help anything :( Do you know what is possible wrong here?